# Coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\dotsm(x-n)$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

**Question**

> Find the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$  in the expression $$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\dots(x-n)~~.$$

**My approach**

> The coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$. The coefficient of  $x^{n-1}$ is $- \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

But I cannot proceed from here.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finding the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ requires picking $2$ terms from the product to multiply the constants. Thus, we get the coefficient to be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}jk
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{j}{1}k\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{k}{2}k\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{k}{2}((k-2)+2)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(3\binom{k}{3}+2\binom{k}{2}\right)\\
&=3\binom{n+1}{4}+2\binom{n+1}{3}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(3n+2)(n^3-n)}{24}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice Robjohn. Please explain me how can i calculate coefficient of $x^{n-3}$ in $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n),$ thanks

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari: it is pretty much the same except we are picking three terms from the product to multiply the constants. This would require another answer to address fully, so if you still need more detail, it might be best to post another question.

Comment: Thanks robjohn . i have posted her. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582647/product-of-terms-taken-3-at-a-time-in-polynomial-expression

Answer (score 9):

Observe that the coefficient of $x^1$ in $$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$ is $$2\cdot3+1\cdot2+1\cdot3$$

or the coefficient of $x^{4-2}$ in $$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)=(x-1)(x-4)(x-2)(x-3)=(x^2-(1+4)x+1\cdot4)(x^2-(2+3)x+2\cdot3)$$

is $$2\cdot3+(1+4)(2+3)+1\cdot4$$

So, the required sum
$$=\sum_{1\le r_1<r_2\le n}r_1r_2=\dfrac{(\sum_{r=1}^n r)^2-\sum_{r=1}^n r^2}2$$

Comment: +1 What you proved by observation is called [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: @Momo, I know http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html. Just wanted to show the deduction. Thanks for the reference, though

Comment: I didn't mean to say that you do not know it. I just wanted to let the OP know the formula by its name.

Comment: @Momo,Once again thanks for that reference

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: (+1) and congrats to 200k !

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\bracks{x^{n - 2}}\pars{x - 1}\pars{x - 2}\cdots\pars{x - n} =\
> {\Large ?}}$

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\bracks{x^{n - 2}}\pars{x - 1}\pars{x - 2}\cdots\pars{x - n}}} =
\bracks{x^{2 - n}}{\pars{1 - x}\pars{1 - 2x}\cdots\pars{1 - nx} \over x^{n}} =
\bracks{x^{2}}\pars{1 - x}\pars{1 - 2x}\cdots\pars{1 - nx} = {1 \over 2}\,\mrm{f}''\pars{0}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} = \prod_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{1 - kx}}$.

Then $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{note that}\ \bbx{\mrm{f}\pars{0} = 1}~}}$,
\begin{align}
\totald{\ln\pars{\mrm{f}\pars{x}}}{x} & =
{\mrm{f}'\pars{x} \over \mrm{f}\pars{x}} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k \over kx - 1}
\implies
\bbx{\mrm{f}'\pars{0} = -\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k}
\\[5mm]
\totald[2]{\ln\pars{\mrm{f}\pars{x}}}{x} & =
{\mrm{f}''\pars{x}\mrm{f}\pars{x} - \mrm{f}'^{2}\pars{x} \over \mrm{f}^{2}\pars{x}} = -\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{k^{2} \over \pars{kx - 1}^{2}}
\\[5mm] \implies &\
\bbx{\mrm{f}''\pars{0} =
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k}^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\bracks{x^{n - 2}}\pars{x - 1}\pars{x - 2}\cdots\pars{x - n}}} =
{\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k}^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{{n^{2}\pars{n + 1}^{2} \over 4} -
{n\pars{n + 1}\pars{2n + 1} \over 6}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{%
{1 \over 8}\,n^{4} + {1 \over 12}\,n^{3} - {1 \over 8}\,n^{2} - {1 \over 12}\,n} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: What a creative approach. I like it!

Comment: @Sudix Thanks. I guess it was the obvious one.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the long way:
\begin{align}
f_{n}(x) &= (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n) \\
f_{1}(x) &= x-1 \\
f_{2}(x) &= x^2 - 3x + 2 \\
f_{3}(x) &= x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6\\
f_{4}(x) &= x^4 - 10x^3 + 35x^2 = 50x + 24 \\
f_{5}(x) &= x^5 - 15x^4 + 85x^3 - 215x^2 + 274x - 120.
\end{align}
From here it is determined that $[x^n] \, f_{n}(x) = 1$, $[x^{n-1}] \, f_{n}(x) = -\binom{n+1}{2} = s(n+1,n)$ and $[x^{n-2}] \, f_{n}(x) \in \{ 2, 11, 35, 85, 175, \cdots \}$. This pattern follows the (signed) Stirling numbers of the first kind, $s(n+2,n)$ or 
$$[x^{n-2}] \, f_{n}(x) = \frac{(n-1) (n) (n+1) (3 n + 2)}{4!} = s(n+1, n-1).$$ 
One may compare the values obtained to [A000914](http://oeis.org/A000914).

Comment: Your formula seems to be for $\left[x^{n-1}\right]f_{n+1}(x)$. Otherwise, I get the same answer.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, after correcting the offset the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

For $~x^{n-1}~$ the coefficient would be sum of the roots that is $~1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+n~$ for $~x^{n-2}~$ coefficient would be sum of roots taken two at a time that is $~1.2+2.3+3.4+4.5+\cdots+(n-1)n~$ so let it be $~S~$ them $~S~$ can be find using steps below
$$(1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+n)^2=(1^2+2^2+3^3+\cdots+n^2)+2(1.2+2.3+3.4+\cdots+(n-1)n)$$ 
So 
$$(1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+n)^2=(1^2+2^2+3^3+\cdots+n^2)+2(S)$$

So this can be find as we know sum of $~n~$ natural no 
That is $~\frac{1}{2}\{n(n+1)\}~$ and sum of squares of first $~n~$ natural number is $~\frac{1}{6}\{n(n+1)(2n+1)\}~$ so this value can be found

Thanks for opportunity to solve the problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.