# How to find all the binomial coefficients for the given equation?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Given the equation

$$x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\ldots(x-100),$$

how can I efficiently calculate the coefficients of $x^1,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ without actually multiplying the terms?

Comment: [*This question*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027141/find-the-coefficient-of-x70-in-x1-1x2-2x3-3-cdotsx12-12) may be relevant.

Comment: Search for "Stirling numbers of the first kind". IIRC the same question came up very recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please access [OEIS sequence A008276](https://oeis.org/A008276) for information. You can use the recurrence to calculate the
coefficients. It is
 $$T(n,k) = T(n-1,k) - (n-1)T(n-1,k-1).$$
For example, given
$$ x(x-1)(x-2) = 1x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x + 0 $$
then compute
$$ x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = 1x^4 - 6x^3 + 11x^2 - 6x + 0$$
as follows:
$$ 1 = 1,\quad -6 = -3 - 3\cdot1,\quad
 +11 = +2 - 3\cdot-3, \quad-6 = 0 - 3\cdot 2,\quad
0 = 0.$$